# A basic reference on odometers

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am looking for a relatively simple reference on the topic of odometers.

I've been recently interested in the topic of subshifts, which to me mean invariant closed subsystems of $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ with respect to the natural action. As such the topic of odometers keeps popping up. Is there a neat survey on the topics of such odometers for a novice on the subject?

I have seen various short reminders on the subject popping up, but I was hoping for a reference discussing their uses and importance. For example I have seen them popping up in the context of equicontinuous factors. They also seem like some sort of universal objects in these setting.

I would appreciate any relevant reference or insight.

Comment: Presumably you have looked at the Wikipedia article [Markov odometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_odometer) and its references and further reading

Comment: @Henry I have looked at it. But I assumed that since they go through Bratteli-Vershik diagrams first, I assumed that there should be ones just dealing with classic odometers. I'm seeking to get a basic understanding of what are their explicit properties.

Comment: Maybe http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa70/aa7022.pdf